# File system for database write-ahead log under Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, journal

I'm looking for a custom file system that would allow me to perform fastest fsync calls so I can put my application's write ahead log there under Linux.

For me the file system should be simplest a single file that represents the image of the disk that I can write/read and call fsync for.

I know that Oracle sometimes uses its own file system to put the journal on to make it fastest.

I assume that somebody had solved this problem before...

Comment: How about good ol' `tmpfs`? A ramdisk should be *very, very* fast - especially compared to anything which involves comms outside the southbridge.

Comment: See: I need fast fsync... You can't fsync tmpfs as it gone when the OS or HW crashes.

Comment: You didn't mention a need for persistence. "Fast fsync" just means "data is *quickly* pushed out of caches onto filesystem." http://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync Perhaps the good people at Serverfault would be better suited to answer your query? Voted to migrate. (I've seen solutions where data is *quickly* pushed to tmpfs, and another `ionice`d process then copies it onto something else - perhaps a SSD?)

Comment: Fast fsync means that after fsync I can assume the durability of the data on the storage, and fast means "fast" :-)

Comment: @Piskvor if you're not going to persist [WAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging) (sic!) then writing to /dev/null will be faster than using tmpfs ;-)